# Unity 3D: Game Object interaction

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unityscript

Assuming we have one first person character and several NPC AIs. The first person character should be able to talk to the NPC AI's (via dialog service). My problem is: How should I "connect" the two game objects (FPC and NPC) to each other?

So he can basically walk around and talk to them, then they answer something, and the first person character may choose an option.

I see several options here:

1. add a public variable to 'first person character'. this public
   variable will hold the NPC AI. So the NPC AI and first person
   character can talk to each other via functions on both classes.
2. Add a class 'DialogService' which implements the observer pattern.
   So there will be several publishers and subscribers. My problem here
   is how to hook up the NPCs and first person character to each other
3. Maybe you have a better alternative?

Answer (score 3):

If you're looking for a simple solution, I could offer this:

Inside of the character's `GameObject` have another `GameObject` called, let's say, "Dialog Collider". Add a collider component to that game object, make it (the collider) a trigger. Also, I would advise you to make the collider a cylinder with a larger radius so that you can enter dialog without actually colliding with another character.

Add a script your player character that starts the dialog when the "Dialog Collider" enters the collision with another GameObject of same name/tag. At this point I presume you would have the same setup for all game character: they all should have a "Dialog Collider" `GameObject` inside of the main GameObject, if they have a dialog option to begin with that is.

That way you can leave the collision detection to the UnityEngine and not check for it every frame.

Also, I'd advise to make a generic `Dialog` script; make it an abstract class that you can inherit from to override some methods so you'd have all the basic functionality right from the start and enough flexibility to change/extend the behaviour of the NPC later on.

Or make a IDialogCharacter interface and implement the methods and dialogs manually for every class; use polymorphism to your advantage to check for the IDialogCharacter interface if you prefer composition over inheritance.

As the hooking up part - when the collision begins your player character will be able to fetch the script (first get the colliding GameObject, then the script component) of the other character and request the dialog start from the other character or get some data object from the other character and start the dialog.

Comment: You could also just have the players click on the NPC's and have that be the beginning of the interaction

Comment: Method of interaction is really not important, but usually you would be prompted when a dialog is available; usually when you're close enough to the target.

As the hooking part, I really feel it's easy with Unity's component-based approach to access a target GameObject's component and start a sequence, get data or start a coroutine.

Comment: Ooh I see, sorry, I misunderstood the question. Your way does seem like the way to go then!